# Convertir Objeto a Array en angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Quiero transformar un objeto a un arreglo en Angular con solo los valores de "value"

Objeto principal:

```
{
    "pinnedFields": {
        "value": [
            "perfil.birthday",
            "perfil.address",
            "perfil.locale",
            "perfil.photo",
            "perfil.customId"
        ]
    }
}
```

Como quiero transformarlo:

```
[
   "perfil.birthday",
   "perfil.address",
   "perfil.locale",
   "perfil.photo",
   "perfil.customId"
]
```

En esta imagen es como llamo al servicio y me devuelve el objeto mencionado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es como quiero recorrerla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que recibo y no puedo obtener los datos para mandarlo a la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `obj = obj.pinnedFields.value`?

Comment: antes que todo gracias, pero no me funciona asi porque ese objeto me llega de un observable y necesito mandarlo como un array.

Comment: Si el observable regresa ese objeto, obviamente tiene que funcionar, en caso de que ocupes algo mas especifico, por favor pon mas código completo, que recibes de donde lo recibes, como lo recibes, y a donde lo quieres enviar,

Comment: Perfecto, ya modifique la pregunta con el codigo que tengo hasta ahora.

Comment: Como lo subscribes a un Observable, creo que lo único que tienes que hacer es usar el pipe async.  como en este ejemplo `*ngFor="let field of (pinnedFields$ | async)?.value"`

Comment: Lo pude resolver, no era simplemente colocar  pinnedFields.value... Haciendo la suscripcion desde el template tenia que recorrer todo el objeto desde el principio, por ejemplo si tenia un suscribe de esta manera: 
*ngIf="(fieldPinneds$ | async as fieldPinneds)"
Tengo que hacer el recorrido for de la siguiente manera:
*ngFor="let field of fieldPinneds.pinnedFields.value"

Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)